# Use of underscores and earmuffs

Tags: communication

I have seen underscores and earmuffs (like `_good_` or `*good*`) frequently used in conversations among programmers. All I know is that underscores are used to denote private variables or methods in languages like C, Python etc. and  earmuffs are the preferred way of indicating that something is a global variable.

Do these have any other punctuational meaning when they are used outside code, in mailing lists etc? Does the highlighted word have any hidden meaning or expression added to it? Or, are they just like air quotes?

Comment: Leading underscores can cause problems in C and C++, since some combinations of underscores and following characters and scopes are explicitly reserved for implementation use.

Comment: This belongs on http://english.stackexchange.com/. Also, `*`'s are called asterisks or stars... earmuffs lolz, have u been watching too much wedding crashers recently?

Comment: @ThomasEding, I know stars and asterisks. Scope of questions might have changed, but this question belonged on this SE 2 years ago. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earmuff_convention

Answer (score 18, accepted):

They tend to be used for emphasis:

```
No, that's *my* monkey.
```

or

```
No, that's _my_ monkey.
```

Asterisks can also be used to denote an action the person is supposedly doing at the time of the comment:

```
No, that's my monkey. *snatches monkey*
```

Or a description to apply to the comment

```
*firmly* No, that's my monkey.
```

In the examples you give though think of them as bold or italic for text that doesn't support rich text.

Comment: And a \*fine\* monkey it is, too.

Comment: I tend to think that `*this is bold*` and `/this is italics/`. Never have I seen `_this is something new to me_`.

Comment: @Thomas. No, `*this is emphasis*` and `/this is the use/mention distinction/` (both of these would be italics in formatted text). Other things that would go in italics, such as book or ship names, are left unformatted.

Answer (score 7):

This is not something that is specific to programmers, but occurs in electronical communications in general.

The underscores are used to mean underlining, and the asterisks are ment to indicate an action.

Example:

```
This is a _really_awesome_ feature. *clapping*
```

Answer (score 5):

In short...

- `*Earmuffs*` usually denote actions, e.g. "`Wow, that's pretty funny! *Laugh*`"
- `_Underscores_` usually denote underlining.  Used for emphasis.
- I've also seen `/slashes/` used to either suggest *italicization* or to refer to a 4chan board.

Answer (score 2):

It is just formatting for plain-text, very simple markup:

- `*something*` smeans that text should be **bold**.
- `_something_` means underlined.
- `/something/` is *italic*.

And yes, the stack exchange formatter messes them up and makes *bold* and *underscored* **italic**, and /italic/ is *nothing*. :)

Comment: SE uses correct [markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/).  The older convention you mention isn't all that widely recognized any more, except among us more "old school" types, as evidenced by this question.